# How do I configure mix.exs to make umbrella project apps share the same version?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I want to define the version in the root mix.exs. The project in apps can read this version. Can it be configured like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

root `mix.exs`:

```
defmodule MyCoolUmbrellaApp.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :my_cool_umbrella_app,
     version: "1.0",
     apps_path: "apps",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     deps: deps()]
  end

  defp deps do
    [

   ]
  end
end
```

code in one of the apps in the umbrella:

```
defmodule SomeApp.SomeModule do

  def some_function() do
    project = Mix.Project.get.project
    app     = project[:app]
    version = project[:version]
```